# Failed to create parametrized testcase in python

Tags: python, pytest

I'm a bit new to python, but in my current task I have to create parametrized testcase. Given the following testcase written in python (python 3)

```
import pytest

from tests.fixtures import create_empty_database 

class TestCreateMssql(object):

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("table, item_names, item_types, ddl" [
     ("special", ["id"], ["INTEGER"], """create or replace TABLE {table} (\n\t"id" NUMBER(38,0));"""),
     ("regular", ["id"], ["INTEGER"], """create or replace TABLE {table} (\n\t"id" NUMBER(38,0));""")
    ])
    def test_create(self, create_empty_database, table, item_names, item_types, ddl):
        pass
```

When I want to run this testcase via pytest:

```
CONFIG_LOCAL=../config_test.py pytest --setup-show tests/functional/test_create.py
```

I get the following error message:

```
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("table, item_names, item_types, ddl" [
E   TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

***Note***

The following snippet is from the same repository and it works, but I don't see any major difference, why the above fail, but this is OK:

```
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("schema, expected", [
    ("dbo", {"tables": ["regular", "special"]}),
    ("non_existing", {"tables": []}),
    ])
    def test_list_tables(self, create_empty_database, schema, expected):
```

Can anybody help me, what did I wrong?

Comment: You're missing a comma between `"` and `[`, resulting in a subscript operation rather than a list creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("table, item_names, item_types, ddl" ,[
     ("special", ["id"], ["INTEGER"], """create or replace TABLE {table} (\n\t"id" NUMBER(38,0));"""),
     ("regular", ["id"], ["INTEGER"], """create or replace TABLE {table} (\n\t"id" NUMBER(38,0));""")
    ])
def test_create( table, item_names, item_types, ddl):
    pass
```

missing a comma after `ddl"`